# Custom filter to replace certain string characters in a json date returned from Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, date, sharepoint

I'm working with json data returned from an Angularjs get request. This data is coming from a Sharepoint list.

The date is a json date string and looks like this `/Date(350697600000)/`

So I am working with Angularjs and I need to display this date the "normal" way or as I want it to look. The json data is an array of objects so I'm displaying the data with ng-repeat in an unordered list. I'm trying to make a custom filter that will replace /Date( and )/ with an empty string, that is I just want the numbers. I need each json date in this array of objects to convert when it is being displayed on my page.

This is what I have so far in my custom filter:

```
app.filter('dateFilter', function() {
   return function(obj) {
      return obj.replace(/\/([^a-zA-Z])\/ /gi, "");
   }    
});
```

My html code looks like this:

```
<li class="adv_li adv_li_birthday" ng-repeat="b in birthdays">
   <div id="adv_birthday" ng-bind="b.Birthday | dateFilter | date:'d. MMMM yyyy'"></div>
   <div ng-bind="b.Employee.Name"></div>
</li>
```

As everybody could guess my filter is not working. I don't really know how to use .replace() or even if using a custom filter to solve this is the best idea. I could use some help with this. Hope my question is not to vague.

Thx in advance everybody!

Comment: Yes, this might be a good use case for a filter. Have a look at moment.js if you haven't yet, it may offer the feature you're seeking for already

Comment: Did you have a look at Angular's [`date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) yet?

Comment: Don't know if I can use moment in this project, beeing code that is injected into sharepoint webparts. But I'm checking it out. Is there know way to get what I have to work?

Comment: yeah I'm using the date angular filter there and it doesn't seem to be able to convert this string...don't think it can, have google it a little

Comment: the date filter can only filter the number part if I copy-paste it in instead of b.Birthday...I need to get rid of /Date( and )/

Comment: Ok I see that moment can parse exactly this string, gonna check if I can add moment.js to this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for date time parsing and manipulation. This time format is called Unix Epoch and in Moment you would write somthing like

```
var date = moment('Date(350697600000)')
```

Comment: I think it's better if you suppress 'Date' and add a format, so...  moment(350697600000).format("yourFormat")

Comment: In most cases Moment.js would work perfectly but because I'm using ng-repeat in Angularjs a custom filter works better, less extra code I have to write.

Comment: Is it not possible to use Moment inside a filter? I'm no Angular expert but I would think that  would be possible.

Comment: Like this:
inline `app.filter('dateFilter', function() {
   return function(obj) {
      return moment(obj).toDate();
   }    
});`

Comment: Yeah you could do that, just extra <script> that I don't need to add to my Sharepoint webparts :) ...and not even sure if moment would work with Sharepoint anyways, probably though.

Comment: I agree that it is not good to add extra script tags when not needed but I use Moment and Underscore so extensively I almost add them to all my projects :)

Comment: Started to notice that the other solution was sometimes messing with the dates before I displayed them. Changing them which is weird. I was getting them right from Sharepoint but at some point in my code they sometimes changed, and I found out that it was happening in my dateFilter. So I instead tried moment and now the dates are appearing right. So I think moment.js is a better solution :) - takk Baldur

Answer (score 1):

I have two theories, I'll address them both.

First of, I think your filter should return a date, also, I think the regex could be improved upon.

```
app.filter('dateFilter', function() {
   return function(obj) {
      return new Date(parseInt(obj.replace(/\D/g, '')));
   }    
});
```

I am using that particular return statement to get a date from the same sort of format, although it's not in an angular project.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This seems to have done the trick :D ...changed it to exactly this and it works finally :) ...to bad I can't up vote yet!

ps. Takk Flati ;)